# Including .cpp in header file redefinition error - Implementing Generic Stack

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, stack

For my CS Data Structures class, I am implementing a Generic Stack using linked list. However, I am getting "Redefinition of .... " errors for all my constructors and functions in my .cpp file. The header file, "Stach.h", was given by the instructor, and at the end she included "Stack.cpp". Everything works fine when I comment out that line, but she wants it there. 
Anybody ever heard of this?

Thanks guys,

David

Comment: Including a source file? Pretty nasty...

Comment: did she give you any build instructions?

Comment: Yeah, let's see stack.cpp and stack.h.  Including a .cpp file in a header file is unusual and if it breaks the build I suspect you and the professor aren't communicating well.

Comment: Her instructions:
Note that classes templates can not be compiled with separate compilation. Here, you must compile Stack.cpp and client code together as follows:
1) use "include" directive to include Stack.cpp at the end of Stack.h
2)"include" Stack.h in client code
3)Compile the client code

I'm pretty sure I followed those steps but I keep getting the same error. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time that I have included a `.cpp` file is when I wanted to put the implementation of a template in a `.cpp` file so that my editor recognized it as C++ instead of C.  Is the implementation of the stack a template?

If it is, then the implementation of the template methods have to be available to compilation units that are using them.  You usually use `.ipp` or `.tcc` for *template* implementation files if you are going to implement somewhere other than in the header itself.  This is what [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and a number of other libraries do.  If this is the case, then you should not be compiling *stack.cpp* since the compiler will take care of that when your client or driver program includes the header file.

Comment: Thanks that was it, I was using xcode so it must have compiled everything together. I ran it using terminal just compiling the main which includes the header file and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor is wrong. You don't include `cpp` files in header files.

The compiler will process them everywhere the header is included. If you include the header in a file, all functions implemented in the `cpp` files will be defined for that translation unit. If you include it in multiple places, multiple translation units will have contain the same symbol, and thus result in the linker error you mentioned.

What could work is if you declare the implementations as `inline`, but it's still pretty nasty.

EDIT: Seeing how the classes are templates, I can think of one problem being that you specialize it to the same type twice. I would remove the `cpp` file from the compilation, although, if you can, you should actually change the extension to `impl` or something else. That way, the compiler will not compile it separately, but it will still be available for the files that specialize your class.

Comment: Consider how templates are implemented ... usually `.tcc` or `.ipp` files instead of `.cpp` files but same concept

Comment: @D.Shawley it's not at all the same concept. Templates generate symbols only when specialized.

Comment: I've seen cases where it made sense.  For example, suppose you have a function you need to use and it's in ..\foo\foo.cpp, but it can't be built as a .lib for some reason (eg, it builds only as 32-bit and you need 64).  The header file foo.h might simply do "#include <..\foo\foo.cpp>" and nothing more.  Though such cases are rare, it's a perfectly legit solution.

Comment: @CareyGregory in those cases, it's a mere hack. I doubt someone still learning should be taught to do things like that. Just because it's written in some production code, doesn't make it okay. I don't think this is ever the solution to anything.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - note that in his comment he stated that they are using templates

Comment: @D.Shawley ah I didn't follow the comments. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: in your Stach.h file, you include the Stach.cpp file using the #include directive, which is copy-paste in preprocessor-time the code of Stach.cpp inside the Stach.h file
 probably your CMakeLists.txt file, in the command << set(SOURCE_FILES ..)>> you also link both Stach.h and Stach.cpp file . 
So, the code of Stach.cpp exists in Stach.h and Stach.cpp itself, so the linker notifies you that redefinition exists.
QuickFix: Change filename of Stach.cpp to Stach.anotherExtension (see the previous comments :) )
BestFix: Remove Stach.cpp from CMakeLists.txt